# Merging two sorted linked list in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to code an algo to merge two sorted linked lists. I am not able to understand why this doesn't give me the correct answer. Why does the answer does not have memory of the earlier assignments, it just returns the most recent assignment being done. (i.e a linked list of length 1). I am creating an initial node called `cur`, then I am adding `next`s to it depending on the values of `l1` and `l2` and doing `cur.next` every time. Thanks

```
struct ListNode {
  int val;
  ListNode* next;
  ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr){};
  ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr){};
  ListNode(int x, ListNode* next) : val(x), next(next){};
};

ListNode* mergeTwoLists(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
  ListNode cur;
  ListNode* ans = new ListNode;
  ans = &cur;

  while (l1 && l2) {
    if (l1->val < l2->val) {
      ListNode temp(l1->val);
      cur.next = &temp;
      l1 = l1->next;
      cur = *(cur.next);
    } else {
      ListNode temp(l2->val);
      cur.next = &temp;
      l2 = l2->next;
      cur = *(cur.next);
    }
  }
  if (l1) {
    cur.next = (l1);
  }
  if (l2) {
    cur.next = (l2);
  }
  return ans->next;
};
```

Comment: Your cur should be a pointer. Plus you're leaking on declaring ans. Not relevant but...

Comment: You allocate a `ListNode` with `ListNode* ans = new ListNode;`. What do you think happens to that allocated block when you overwrite the pointer with `ans = &cur;`?

Comment: I might be wrong, but ans shouldnt change at all, because it points to the initial cur, I also used print statements to verify this

Comment: The problem with `ans` is that once you allocate with `ListNode* ans = new ListNode;`, `ans` holds the starting address to the block of memory you have allocated. When you set `ans = &cur;`, you overwrite the beginning address of the allocated block held by `ans` with the address of the local variable `cur`. So it makes no sense to allocate `ans` just to lose the address to the allocated block by assigning the address of `cur` to `ans`. You could have just done `ListNode* ans = &cur;` to begin with an avoid the allocation altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you are not moving `cur` forward so that a new node can be appended to the list. As you have it now `cur.next = &temp` is just resetting the `next` pointer every time. Also, since the `temp` variable is local to the scope of the `if` branches, when you do `cur.next = &temp` you are setting the `next` pointer to an object that will disappear every time the `if` statement ends, causing a dangling pointer. It's better to dynamically allocate:

```
ListNode ans;
ListNode* cur = &ans;
while (l1 && l2) {
  if (l1->val < l2->val) {
    cur->next = new ListNode(l1->val);
    l1 = l1->next;
  } else {
    cur->next = new ListNode(l2->val);
    l2 = l2->next;
  }
  cur = cur->next;
}
if (l1)
  cur->next = l1;
else
  cur->next = l2;
return ans.next;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I am doing cur=*(cur.next), which should move cur forward. I understand that it is better to dynamically allocate, but I just wanted to understand why this doesnt work.

Comment: @Aman because you're making a copy each time you do that. I dont think you understand pointers based on your code and the questions you're asking. Best thing to do is slow down and read up.

Answer (score 0):

Lets walk through the code you have inside the `if` blocks to try and understand what is going on.

```
ListNode temp(l1->val);
cur.next = &temp;
l1 = l1->next;
cur = *(cur.next);
```

Line #1 creates a new ListNode variable called temp in a newly allocated memory location. Lets say the address of this memory location is X123. At this memory location, temp.val stores l1->val and temp.next is nullptr.

Line #2 asks to store the address of the temp variable in cur.next so cur.next will be storing X123 after Line #2 has executed.

Line #3 asks to make l1 point to l1->next. This is doing what you expect.

Now pay close attention to Line #4. It isn't doing what you think it is doing. In a comment above, you said:

> I am doing cur=*(cur.next), which should move cur forward.

But this is not exactly correct. "Moving cur forward" does not make sense because cur is not a pointer to ListNode, it is simply a ListNode object. So  Line #4 is asking to copy the object stored at the memory location cur.next (i.e. memory location X123), and paste it into the memory location occupied by cur. In other words, it is asking to copy the temp object into the memory location occupied by the cur object. So after Line #4 executes, cur.val will store whatever was in temp.val (i.e. the most recent l1->val), and cur.next will store whatever was in temp.next (i.e. nullptr).

In doing so you lose the pointer to temp's memory location X123, since cur.next was storing this and now you have overwritten it with nullptr! This is why at the end you have a cur with the last (most recent) assignment. All the earlier assignments are lost since you overwrite the contents of cur with new stuff in each iteration. You never "move cur forward".

The solution is to work with pointers. Have cur be a ListNode* pointer instead of a ListNode object, and try to work your way through the problem.

Hope this helps, and welcome to SO. Cheers!